# How to make a protected Excel file using COM class in php

Tags: php, com

My code:

```
<?

    $file = "Book1.xlsx"; 
    $app = new COM("Excel.application") or Die ("Did not connect");

    echo "Loaded Excel, version {$app->Version}\n"; 
    $workbooks = $app->Workbooks->open($file);
    echo "open <br>";
    $app->DisplayAlerts = 0;
    $workbooks->Password = '1234';
    echo "pss<br>"; //$workbooks->Saveas($file);
    $app->Wookbooks->Saveas($file);
    echo "save<br>";
    $app->Workbooks->Close();
    $app->Quit;

?>
```

I'd like to make "Book1.xlsx" a protected Excel file. But it didn't work.

I set php_ini file:

```
com.typelib_file =
com.allow_dcom = true com.autoregister_typelib = true
com.autoregister_casesensitive = false com.autoregister_verbose = true

extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
```

I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Please explain "it didn't work": no result, error message, something crashes, ... This helps others to give better answers.

Comment: Slight improvement of readability.

Comment: Slightly sharpened the title

Answer (score 0):

Setting the Password (property) of a workbook only will ask for it if you try to open the book again.
But it will not protect it.
In order to do that, you have the [following method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff193800.aspx)

also note that what you are calling workbooks, is a single workbook. It is important, because Excel already has an object called workbooks, which is the collection of open workbooks.